# Integrate GWT with Google Fusion Tables API

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

I have recently tried to move a visualization project, developed in javascript to GWT, hoping to get better structure and optimised code. As a part of the transfer we also wanted to go from google spreadsheet to fusion tables as our data storage.

I haven't been able to find a good tutorial that supports GWT's web applications or I might just not been able to implement them correctly. I have tried to implement e.g. [Hello World](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/sample_code.html) and [gwt-gdata](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gdata/), with errors as soon as I use any library.

Can anyone please tell me if this is possible, if there is any way to send requests to the Fusion Tables using GWT?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve this in the end?

Comment: No I haven't. We gave up on fusion tables. We also recently moved away from google spreadsheet to our own server.